# Changing spring MissingServletRequestPartException message

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm using spring-boot-starter-web and I'd like to change the message returned from an upload request mapping:

```
@RequestMapping("/upload")
public @ResponseBody String upload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file){...}
```

What I have for a HTTP/1.1 404 Not found is:

```
{"timestamp":1462064481371,"status":404,"error":"Not Found",
"exception":"org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException",
"message":"Required request part 'file' is not present","path":"/upload"}
```

I want to change **"Required request part 'file' is not present"** for something like **"Parameter is missing**.

Is there an easy way to get this done with annotations?

If possible, I'd like to suppress the exception information as well.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the best solution so far is re-writing the entire ResponseBody:

```
    @ExceptionHandler(MissingServletRequestPartException.class)
    public @ResponseBody Map<String,String> handleMissingServletRequestPartException(Exception  exception, HttpServletResponse response) {
        Map<String,String> errorMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
        errorMap.put("message","missing parameter");
        response.setStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value());
        return errorMap;
    }
```

...

{"message":"missing parameter"}

Answer (score 0):

This Exception is handled by the [ResponseEntityExceptionHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.html).
You could extend this and override the method [handleMissingServletRequestPart](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.html#handleMissingServletRequestPart-org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException-org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders-org.springframework.http.HttpStatus-org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest-). This could look for example like this:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RequestExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

  @Override
  protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMissingServletRequestPart(MissingServletRequestPartException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
    MyCustomErrorResource error = new MyCustomErrorResource("missing parameter");
    return handleExceptionInternal(ex, error, headers, status, request);
  }
}
```